# How can I get useState value I mean allResults value, though async await occur asynchronous behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I need to get allResults value but it gives me an empty array. Because of async behavior. So, what can I do to get three API values by setting useState.

```
const [allResults, setSearchResults] = useState<any>([]);

  async function search() {
    try {
      const searchResults = await Promise.allSettled([
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:8000/v1/tokens?blockchain_like=${searchTerm}`
        ).then((res) => res.json()),
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:8000/v1/collections?blockchain_like=${searchTerm}`
        ).then((res) => res.json()),
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:8000/v1/users?username_like=${searchTerm}`
        ).then((res) => res.json()),
      ]);
      console.log(searchResults);
      setSearchResults(searchResults); // set search result value in useState
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  console.log(allResults); // It's occur before searchResults console.log (because async behaviour).
```

Comment: If you are trying to log `allResults` with latest value, use a `useEffect` with `allResults` as the dependency. 
     `useEffect(() => {
         console.log(allResults)
     },[allResults]) `

Comment: But I need to pass allResults value child component

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
Promise.allSettled([
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:8000/v1/tokens?blockchain_like=${searchTerm}`
        ).then((res) => res.json()),
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:8000/v1/collections?blockchain_like=${searchTerm}`
        ).then((res) => res.json()),
        fetch(
          `http://localhost:8000/v1/users?username_like=${searchTerm}`
        ).then((res) => res.json()),
      ]).then((results) => setSearchResults(results));
```

Comment: When I console.log results then I get data but it's not set useState like setSearchResults.

Comment: It's not working...!!!